# MariaDB Fulltext Search with hyphen/dash

Tags: mysql, mariadb, full-text-search

We are moving to MariaDB 10.1 from MySQL 5.6 and have a  Fulltext index for product descriptions and product numbers (InnoDB). A large number of our product numbers have a dash/hyphen in them like "Pf-2". If I search for that in MySQL it would search for "PF" and "2", both of which are under 3 characters and would return an empty result. Is it possible to have MariaDB treat the hyphen as a letter character instead of a stop/word break character? In MySQL the only way to do this with UTF8 character sets was to do a custom build of MySQL.

Comment: You could set `innodb-ft-min-token-size=1` and run your search as `select * from t1 where match(c) against ('"Pf-2"')`, this way your `Pf-2` will be found. Of course, it will also find `Pf 2`, `Pf++2` and such, so if it's a problem, then it is not going to work for you.

Comment: What engine is the table?

Comment: Engine will be XtraDB and InnoDB. 

`innodb-ft-min-token-size=1` is not a viable solution with a table of our size.

Answer (score 2):

You could quote the query string:

```
select *
from mytable
where  match(mycol) against  ('+"Pf-2"' in boolean mode)>0.0;
```

Comment: Might be related to your sample. I had a sample where a searched for full words, like `mach (mycol) against (+"Baden-Württemberg" in boolean mode) > 0.0`, and here it worked. But I did not find an official documentation about this.

Comment: I think it worked because both sides of words joined by the dash are over 2 letters. It would work for me if I set innodb-ft-min-token-size=1 but with the size of my database that is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using:

```
`SELECT * FROM  `Product` WHERE MATCH(`title`, `number`, `shortDescription`, `rawDescription`, `rawColors`)
AGAINST('PF-2' IN BOOLEAN MODE) OR `number` LIKE '%PF-2%'
```

Not ideal, but it got the job done until we get Sphinx running to replace the fulltext searches.